# Getting a different code outcome on different servers

Tags: php, ajax

[image]
This is updated based on an answer, but i still have a problem.

```
var dataString = $("#acc_form").serialize();
var action = $("#acc_form").attr('action');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType:"JSON",
url: action,
data: dataString,
success: function(res){
                if(res.status === 'error'){
                    console.log('Error!!!');
                } else{
                    console.log('Success!!!');
                }
            }


});
```

Here is where i do the check, and also where i am confused. my else statement looks wrong.

```
$desired_email = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$email_exist_check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email='$desired_email'") or die(mysql_error());
$email_exist = mysqli_num_rows($email_exist_check);
if ($email_exist == 0) {
    //performs insert query

    } else {

header('Content-type: application/json');           
$res['status'] = 'error';    

echo json_encode($res);  

            }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am new to jQuery and ajax and using json

Comment: Show the full code, otherwise people will just take a stab in the dark at your `if(//email doesnt exist){ ....` code as I assume that's the condition that returns `success`.

Comment: I added some more info. hopefully that helps. should i return 1 in the if statement?

Comment: Are you sure your query isn't failing? What is `$desired_email`...?

Comment: that is from a form. 
Currently, It will create the user if the email doesnt exist and go to cashcheck_order.php.
If it does exist it will go to that page, create no user, then fail

Answer (score 0):

Because you've returned a json array, even check email is invalid. You need to process the response data in success of ajax function. The error callback only works when server return status code on header (it isn't status in response data), i called it is **Solution 1**. In **Solution 2**, i solve it by return a header in PHP code.

Solution 1: Solve it on client (javascript)

```
//...
success: function(res){
// Use json parse method to parse the response data if it is string.
// If you have been to set dataType: 'json', it's ok. Can ignore this comment & code.
// res = JSON.parse(res);

status = res.status;

if(status == 'error'){
//Process the error in here
}
}
//...
```

Full ajax function example:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                data: {email: 'vuong@gmail.com'},
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(res){
                    if(res.status === 'error'){
                        console.log('Error!!!');
                    } else{
                        console.log('Success!!!');
                    }
                }
            });
```

It's work on my workplace!

[image: My development Network tab on Chrome]

Solution 2: Solve it on server (php)

```
// Add it to before `echo` line
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
```

You only need to choose once in both. Good luck!

Sorry all because my English is not good.

Comment: i went with solution 1 and i am still confused. can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: I added full example ajax function. Please focus it.

Comment: Thank you. Posted my ajax. i tried your example. does my php else statement look correct? still not working. :/

Comment: I've added development view (Network tab). Can you add your view to show the response in your post?

Comment: posted. thats all i got when i clicked create. Not much seems to be happening. if the email does not exist it will create the account...

Comment: Ok. Ill get that for you, first. How do i set the status = 'error'? Do i have to convert it to JSON? I feel like that is where my problem may be.

Comment: No, when you set dataType: 'json', you dont need to parse the response. I have no idea if i cant see the response. 

Ahhh, you can try change $_POST to $_GET var in `process_account.php` and make real request in navigation. I think it is quickly to show the response.